# How can I generate multiple divs dynamically on click?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a a web app where the user has to enter a product number and next to the input field is an arrow that the user clicks. On click, there is a check to ensure the number the user entered is a valid product number (it checks it against an array of valid numbers) and if it's valid, it should show and populate div with information related to that product.

If the user enters the same number again and clicks the arrow again, the same div should show up but underneath the first div. If the user enters another valid number (not same number), it will show a div with that product info underneath the first div. If user enters an invalid number, then it should throw an error saying invalid div. The last bit is not important, just that it should not generate another div.

What I have done so far is a show-hide method to show/hide div in my html file based on whether or not the number is valid. However, I would like generate multiple divs if number is valid (multiple transactionDetails div shown below). I was wondering how can I do that?

Here's my html snippet:

```
<input class="numberInput" formControlName="ProductNumber" type="number" placeholder="{{'EnterNumber' | translate}}" [ngClass]="displayErrors ? 'inputRedBorder': 'input'" style="width:150px !important;"/>

    <span (click)="validateNumber()">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 8 8" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <path d="M5 0v2h-5v1h5v2l3-2.53-3-2.47z" transform="translate(0 1)" />
        </svg>
    </span>

  <div class="transactionDetails grid" *ngIf="showResults">
    <span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
        <path d="M4 0c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm-1.5 1.78l1.5 1.5 1.5-1.5.72.72-1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.72.72-1.5-1.5-1.5 1.5-.72-.72 1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.72-.72z" />
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="image">{{product.image}}</span>
    <span>
        <div class="itemDescriptionText-regular">{{product.number}}</div>
        <div class="itemDescriptionText-regular">{{product.description}}</div>
        <div class="itemDescriptionText-bold">{{product.style}}</div>
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div style="padding-left:20px;padding-bottom:10px;">Price </div>
        <div><input class="transactionInput" placeholder="{{'EnterPrice' | translate}}"/>x</div>
    </span>
    <span>
    <div style="text-align:center;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:10px;">Qty</div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type='number' name='quantity' min=0 oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class='qty'/>
    </span>
    <span>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        Total Price 
    </div>
    <div><br></div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        {{totalAmount}} 
    </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here's my validate function:

```
listOfValidProductNumbers = [ 
  3097165,
  6100256,
  6124380,
  2177422,
  3795377,
  6097961,
  3808804,
  6110164,
  1705466]; 

validateSKU() 
{
   const productNumber = this.transactionForm.get('ProductNumber').value;

    if (this.listOfValidProductNumbers.indexOf(productNumber) > -1 ) {
      this.showResults = true;
    } else {
      this.showResults = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the product object from?
What do you mean by showing multiple divs?
Does multiple products exist with the same product number?
More info needed...

Comment: @KiranReddy I updated the post to show the products array. Right now, it's just a hardcoded list but I will hook it up to get productnumbers from api later. For multiple divs, if I type in one of the numbers in the array above, then click on the arrow, it should show/generate the div in my html with class="transactionDetails grid" and return the product info related to that number. E.g. generate the div above. If I type in the same number again or another valid number, it should show the another transactionDetails div underneath the first generated div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following solution.

Put an Array of products in your typescript file. e.g.

```
private products: Array<product> = [];
```

Whenever your validation returns true, add the new/next product to the Array

```
validateSKU() {
   const productNumber = this.transactionForm.get('ProductNumber').value;

   if (this.listOfValidProductNumbers.indexOf(productNumber) > -1 ) {
      this.products.push(product);
      this.showResults = true;
   } else {
      this.showResults = false;
   }
}
```

And in your HTML-template use *ngFor to present the content of the array. With every new product Angular will extend the list.

```
<div class="transactionDetails grid" *ngIf="showResults">
   <div *ngFor"let product of products"> 
      <span>
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
             <path d="M4 0c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm-1.5 1.78l1.5 1.5 1.5-1.5.72.72-1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.72.72-1.5-1.5-1.5 1.5-.72-.72 1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.72-.72z" />
           </svg>
       </span>
       <span class="image">{{product.image}}</span>
      <span>
        <div class="itemDescriptionText-regular">{{product.number}}</div>
        <div class="itemDescriptionText-regular">{{product.description}}</div>
        <div class="itemDescriptionText-bold">{{product.style}}</div>
     </span>
     <span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div style="padding-left:20px;padding-bottom:10px;">Price </div>
        <div><input class="transactionInput" placeholder="{{'EnterPrice' | translate}}"/>x</div>
    </span>
    <span>
       <div style="text-align:center;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:10px;">Qty</div>
       <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type='number' name='quantity' min=0 oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class='qty'/>
    </span>
    <span>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
       Total Price 
    </div>
    <div><br></div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        {{totalAmount}} 
    </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I want to keep the style of several divs, I should make the div structure like this?: `<div *ngIf="showResults">
          <div *ngFor"let product of products"> 
            <div class="transactionDetails grid"> </div></div></div>` So each div I generate has the style of transactionDetail grid applied to it.

Comment: I was not sure which "div" in general you were talking about. If it is another div inside this block then put a div with *ngFor around it. What you can't do is having *ngFor and *ngIf in the same div. This would cause an Error. So you have definitely to put an extra div inside your *ngIf div. Where you really have to put it at depends on your needs. But to get an unknown amount of values dynamically prompted you have to use the solution with the array in combination with *ngFor.

Comment: ok got it. I think this should work out. I will test in a little bit. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Your're welcome. And I'd really appreciate it if you'd mark this post as solution if it is.